Azure function requests call to CPanel hosted python Flask API giving an "Verifying that you are not a robot"
I am running a Python service in Azure Functions that makes a request using requests module to a Flask API hosted on cPanel. However, I receive a response with the text "Verifying that you are not a robot," and my request does not reach the Flask API endpoint.
I have tested the API call from different Azure regions and encounter the same issue. When I run the same script from my local computer, I do not face this problem. The script reaches the Flask API endpoint and do what needs to be done. Only when I try to achieve the same outcome from Azure, I am getting "Verifying that you are not a robot".
What can be the issue here - it is something specific to Azure Functions, is this a common problem, how do I deal with this?
import requests
import logging

headers = {"THIS":"XXXXXXX"}
job_data = {
      "number": 151, 
      "records":[
          {"row_id":15, "content":"my-1-content-is-here"}, 
          {"row_id":16, "content":"my-2-content-is-here"}
      ]
    }

job_request = requests.post("https://cPanel-flask-hosted-api.net/my-jobs/", headers=headers , json =job_data)

# The request is returning a 200, but the my-jobs is not being run. 
if job_request.status_code == 200:
     logging.info('Job submitted successfully!')
     logging.info(f'{job_request.text}') # it is giving me text "Verifying that you are not a robot"


I checked my server logs, and saw that all the logs where I did use Python requests outside Azure or any other  client, there were some code executed. So, I managed to resolve this by adding a User-Agent. Without the User-Agent, I saw that the request User-Agent was being logged as python-requests/2.32.3.
My new header now looks like this:
headers = {
  "THIS":"XXXXXXX", 
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

I think if I use any of the well known clients it should work. For example, postman  \ insomnia \ curl e.t.c
